# Why do I get error messages when I try to plot this function?

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, special-functions

> **Question**: Why do I get error messages such as "LessEqual::nord: Invalid comparison with 1. -1.59148 I attempted." when I try to plot the function f[z,k] defined below with for example the Plot invocation illustrated below?

```
f[z_, k_] := (
 I E^(-((2 I \[Pi])/k))
   HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(-((2 I \[Pi])/k)), 1, 1 + (I z)/(2 \[Pi])])/(
 2 \[Pi])

Plot[{Abs@f[s, 2]}, {s, -10, 10}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce (10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)).

Comment: I get two of those errors with 12.0.0 with a fresh notebook. Simplify doesn't help, ComplexExpand doesn't help

Comment: Try adding the option `Exclusions -> None`.  I'd say this is a (very minor) bug.  The message should be turned off, while `Plot` is figuring out discontinuities.  You should report it to WRI, imo.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that `Plot` is trying to do some fancy symbolic manipulation beforehand. I'm running V12.0.0 on macOS 10.14.5, and this worked for me, although make sure you use a fresh notebook or clear the definitions for `f` first.

```
f[z_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := 
 Abs[(I E^(-((2 I \[Pi])/k)) HurwitzLerchPhi[E^(-((2 I \[Pi])/k)), 1, 
      1 + (I z)/(2 \[Pi])])/(2 \[Pi])]
Plot[f[s, 2], {s, -10, 10}]
```

This forces Mathematica to only evaluate `f` when it receives a numerical argument.

[image: Plot of f when it only receives numerical arguements.]